# Masking IP address and port number for Web application

Tags: webserver, dns, ip

I have a Web application running on port 89 ( non-standard port) of a Windows 2012 R2 machine. The login page for this application needs to be accessible through a link on my website - let's call it mydomain-llc.com. I have created a button on the home page which currently explicitly provides the IP address and port number for the web server as such :

```
</head><frameset rows="100%" scrolling="yes" border="0">
<frame src="http://x.y.z.t:89/">
</frameset></html>
```

The net result is that when an user clicks the button they are taken to the login form for the web application but the IP address and port number is exposed in the browser address bar as such : `http://x.y.z.t:89/`

How can I mask the Ip address and have it just display a domain level URL such as :

```
mydomain.com/loginform.html
```

I understand that one way to achieve this is to setup a DNS A record at the domain manager level but would it work for an application running on a non-standard port ( port 89 in this case ) ?
Many thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: DNS works for IP, ports are not a consideration. Do you want to mask the port, or are you worried that by using port 89 that DNS won't work?

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, you can mask the IP address through DNS.  However, there's nothing you can do to mask the port: the decision to display it or not is entirely up to the user's web browser.

There are no security implications of exposing the address and port, though: it's trivial for a potential attacker to figure them out.

Answer (score 1):

DNS A record setup with a domain name will work as expected to mask to IP address from view. You will still need :89 after the hostname.

DNS translates IP address (layer 3 protocol)
Port number cannot be masked (layer 4 protocol)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it sounds like you just want to setup your first-server as a reverseproxy

i.e. on mydomain-llc.com you just need in config

```
ProxyPass       /login/  http://x.y.z.t:89/
ProxyPassReverse /login/ http://x.y.z.t:89/
```

Now when people go to http://mydomain-llc.com/login/ their traffic will go through mydomain-llc to x.y.z.t, masking the IP and port from being visible since that's happening on the otherside of mydomain-llc

Answer (score 0):

I think some responders made this a bit too complicated. You can shove the link into an iframe and have the iframe loaded into a webpage on mydomain.com.

Example:

```
cd /var/www/html/mydomain.com/
vi /var/www/html/mydomain.com/login.html
```

On the login page, you can just insert the other site in an iframe:

```
 <iframe src="http://w.x.y.z:89/index.html"></iframe>
```

When someone goes to www.mydomain.com/login.html they'll load the page from the alternative site. The issue with this would be people configuring their browsers to disallow iframes (e.g., IE trusted sites), or possible SSL certificate issues.